# getItemValue() getting the value twice?

Tags: display-template, cswp

I'm working on a `Content Search` WebPart which displays a list of pages. The third line, in my properties, returns a `PublishingPageContentOWSHTML`.

But is it normal that its value appears twice, once my displayTemplate has finished its job? I'm basically getting the value using:

```
var line3 = $getItemValue(ctx, "Line 3");
```

And displaying it in a div. But the result leaves me a bit puzzled;

```
<div><p>​In blandit diam ligula, [...] purus feugiat auctor.</p>​In blandit diam ligula, [...] purus feugiat auctor.</div>
```

I plan on trimming the value later of course, I don't want to display a full paragraph in my list but before that, being new to SharePoint, I have no idea what's going on with my value and why it's appearing twice.

Comment: You can place a debugger and figure out whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

Seems your are not getting a `value` but an `object` with formatting and innerText.

You can test with:

```
var line3 = typeof $getItemValue(ctx, "Line 3");
```

Trace the output to the F12 Dev Tools console

```
console.info('line3',$getItemValue(ctx, "Line 3"));
```

you can then inspect of its an Array or an Object with (named) properties.

Comment: you're right, line3 is an `object`. But how can I handle this then? I tried casting it to a `string` but it doesn't change anything, so is it because of the `PublishingPageContentOWSHTML` ?